Konjunktiv II und Perfekt
Hier ist 2 Sätze. Ein ist in Konjunktiv II und ein ist in Perfekt form.
Konjunktiv II:
"Ich hätte das bloß anders gemacht, dann wären alles anders."
Perfekt:
"Wenn ich das bloß anders gemacht habe, dann wären alles anders."
Sind diese beiden Sätze grammatikalisch korrekt und ist die einzige Unterschied das, dass Satz 1 ein Gefühl des Bedauerns enthält?
Vielen Dank für Ihre Hilfe.

Ich korrigiere mal alles.

Hier sind 2 Sätze. Einer ist im Konjunktiv II und einer ist in Perfekt-Form.

(steht im … / steht in ist in diesem Kontext üblicher.)

Konjunktiv II (Konjunktiv II Perfekt)
„Ich hätte das bloß anders gemacht, dann wäre alles anders.“
Perfekt: (Konjunktiv II Perfekt)
„Wenn ich das bloß anders gemacht hätte, dann wäre alles anders.“

Dieser zweite Satz muss ebenfalls im Konjunktiv II stehen, denn es handelt sich ja explizit nicht um Fakten.

Sind diese beiden Sätze grammatikalisch korrekt und ist die einzige
Unterschied das, dass Satz 1 ein Gefühl des Bedauerns enthält?

Der erste Satz drückt aus, dass eine andere Person etwas auf eine bestimmte Weise gemacht hat. Aber der Sprecher hätte es anders gemacht, wenn er die Arbeit selbst erledigt hätte.

„Hier, ich habe alles nach Datum vorsortiert. … Oh, du guckst ja so komisch? War das falsch?“
— „Nein. Ich hätte das bloß anders gemacht. [lacht] Dann wäre alles anders.“

Es ist also schon eine Art des Bedauerns, aber man muss ja nett sein, wenn jemand anders einem ausnahmsweise eine stumpfsinnige Arbeit abgenommen hat.
Der zweite Satz drückt hingegen explizit das Bedauern des Sprechers darüber aus, dass der Sprecher selbst etwas falsch gemacht hat. Das hängt damit zusammen, dass es sich um eine Wenn-Aussage handelt. Dadurch ist diese Unmittelbarkeit wie im ersten Beispiel nicht mehr gegeben, bei der man sich eine zweite Person dazudenken muss, damit die Aussage einen Sinn ergibt.

Ich denke eher, dass mir den ersten Satz "hätte ich das bloß anders gemacht" gemeint war, aber das kann nur der OP bekannter.
